# Navigation Bar is shown only at the first tabBarController

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I've got a `tabBar` with 3 screens (Home, Favorite and Settings). Use `Storyboard`. All these screens have a `NavigationController`. Navigation Bar is shown only at the first screen - Home, other have no Navigation Bar (no title, no button). Why is this happening?

Upd: I have this problem only on Simulator but on real iPhone everything is good.
My `AppDelegate`:

```
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

Also I have Login page before `TabBarController`, going to `TabBarController` from Login by this method:

```
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let singInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController")
      UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = singInViewController
      self?.present(singInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Attach a screenshot with your storyboard setup.

Comment: I've got the same as the 1ts answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Add Each View Controller Separate Navigation Bar and attach UINavigation Controller to Tab Bar Controller.

[image: Click here for screenshot of storyboard]

Comment: Thanks, I've got the same Storyboard structure. Please, see my update for the question, maybe there is some new info